# Move titlepage before abstract

Tags: titles

In a school report, I have the obligation to use word document to make the title page. It is way easier to export the word document as a pdf and include it than use Latex to try micmic the word document. So the command titlepage was the easiest way to include the figure, but right now the abstract show before the title page. How can I force the titlepage to be the first page

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

%%%title page
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{figure}
\hspace*{-2cm}  
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{pagetitre.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{titlepage}

\begin{abstract}
abstract here
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

A other option was to use the basic title method of the report class, but a blank page appear before the title page. I think it is the conventional way of making title don't like the insertion of huge figure.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your document isn't compilable. Of course, the size of the included pdf may cause a pagebreak

Comment: Copy the line `\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{pagetitre.pdf}`, mark the whole `titlepage` block, hit the delete button, and paste the copied line. Done.

Comment: @Johannes_B I use the no titlepage option of the report class with your comment. The title page now display before the abstract but there is still a blank page before

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I finaly manage to produce a result which okay. The code is certainly horrible I have no doubt but I manage to fix my problem. Can I post my latex code as the answer.

Comment: Use package `pdfpages` to include your titlepage.

Comment: @MathieuL yes, you can self answer (and accept) which clears the question off the unanswered list!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay I'll put the answer later today

Comment: @Johannes_B: I'd write something like that up as an answer, since the current answer seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single-page, stand-alone PDF that you want to use as a title page, I would suggest including it using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=1]{titlepage}% Title page

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here \ldots
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, anyone reading this should use the normal way to make title page which is way more elegant and efficient. This is the result of strict school's rules. I manage to put the title page before the abstract in  this way

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{report} 
 \begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
 \begin{center}
   \hspace*{-1.5cm} 
   \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{titlepage.pdf}
 \end{center}


\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\begin{abstract}
 abstract goes here
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `\includepdf{example-image}` from packae `pdfpages` much easier?

Comment: @Johannes_B I will try it.